# NTLM hash function in Terminal?

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, password

I'm aware there are a number of hash functions available in terminal such as `echo "text" | openssl <hashname>` or `perl -MDigest::SHA -nle 'print Digest::SHA::sha224_hex($_), ":", $_'`. However, I have been unable to find any way of hashing into NTLM.

Is anyone aware of a method (preferably an efficient method) for hashing into NTLM through terminal?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "an efficient method"? - It seems there's something you're not telling us. Why would you require an efficient method if only to hash once? .... Could it be that your real problem is that you want to do lots of hashes and need instead one of the program that tries to bruteforce passwords?

Comment: Please have a glance at my forum post linked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51412536/most-efficient-way-to-hash-each-line-of-a-text-file As you can see, I am trying to hash each line of a text file and therefore a more efficient method is more desirable. Either way, I am just wondering what the command would be to apply the NTLM hash algorithm to even one word let alone numerous lines. Some guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please explain what your original problem (i.e. use for this) is. It's a waste of time trying to answer various subquestions for possible solutions, you might have thought up. It seems likely that there exists a standard solution for your original problem that is much easier to convey. Right now your question does not make sense as the overhead in using seperate commands for hashing (i.e. starting up shell processes) is much more expensive (computationally) than the hasing itself - therefore rendering it futile to optimize the hashing itself.

Comment: As you may have seen, I was provided with an excellent answer by "Jon" on Stack Overflow which proved to be a solution for virtually all the issues I had. I am trying to use the perl Digest:: command to use a hash function and have succeeded in finding numerous functions including Tiger, SHA, Md5, Md2 , Gost etc. However, I have been unable to find a similar function on metacpan.org which provides functionality for the NTLM hash. Therefore, I am reaching out to AskDifferent to see what the command would be to achieve this (if there even is one).

Comment: Then you're asking the question in the wrong place. What you need is not a "command", but rather a perl implementation of the NTLM hash... Multiple such implementations are available on CPAN btw.

Comment: Even if the final answer proves to be computationally inefficient, I am still curious to know what the command for an NTLM hash function is on MaOS

Comment: I don't understand why you focus on "command". It is entirely the wrong focus. It's like asking "It takes too long time when I hammer in nails with my shoe. Please suggest a better shoe".

Comment: @jksoegaard Thank you for the advice, where would you advice enquiring further about this issue then? Out of interest, what is the non-perl implementation of the NTLM hash?

Comment: Your question does not make sense. There exists hundreds of non-perl implementations of the NTLM hash.

Comment: Can't you just describe what you need this for... i.e. why are you trying to build this. Then I can give you the solution very easily I guess. This other thing is quite pointless as you will never get to an efficient solution by having a seperate ntlm hashing command.

Comment: @jksoegaard I was not aware of this. Maybe the better question would be: what is the best way to implement an NTLM hash into a bash script. I would very much appreciate it if you could even help me out in the slightest

Comment: That is still not a good question. Please step back and explain the original problem. I.e. are you trying to crack passwords? - are you trying to create your own authentication system? - or what it is? There's absolutely nothing wrong with wanting to do any of these things, just say so.

Comment: @jksoegaard My use for this is an integration into a bash-based database system which is capable of hashing incoming passwords into the user's desired hashing algorithm. As I have said, I have achieved over 99% of the "project" but am still lacking the functionality for the bash script to be able to hash into NTLM.

Comment: So this is a school assignment? i.e. home work? Anyways, you seem to be deadset on not wanting to reveal why you want to do this, and as such you can never get the actual help you need. But to answer your question, if you want to do exactly what you write (which is not a good idea) - then just replace MD5 in Jons answer with MD4. That will give you NTLM hashes. Remember that the input must be in Unicode.

Comment: @jksoegaard No, I aim for my script to function as the back end of a web interface where people can efficiently hash any string they want into almost any hash function they want. I fail to see how this much detail I am providing you with at the moment is relevant to solving the question at hand of integrating an NTLM function into a bash script...

Comment: It doesn't make any sense at all. There's no way using a "web interface" to hash a single string can be made "efficient" in any real terms of the word. Bash doesn't seem like the most common candidate for creating web backends either? ;-)

Comment: I'm actually trying to help you very much. It is essential though to solve the real problem. Read up on the XY problem here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hash using the NTLM method like this:

```
perl -MAuthen::Passphrase::NTHash -nle 'print Authen::Passphrase::NTHash->new(passphrase => $_)->hash_hex, ":", $_' < infile >> outfile
```

However, according to your comments your question is a XY problem. You're actually really trying to build a web site that allows everyone to hash any string efficiently using any hashing algorithm. For that that purpose, the above mentioned command line is not suitable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response; this is exactly what I was looking for. I have installed this with `cpan install Authen::Perl::NTLM` but I have been promoted that I "may need to install the Authen::Passphrase::NTHash module". Which CPAN module would I need to install to fix this? (I.e. what would be the command(s) to fix this dependancy problem?) Thank you once again :)

Comment: You don't need to install Authen::Perl::NTLM. You need to install Authen::Passphrase::NTHash.

Comment: Thanks, just installed that now but got the error "unrecognised attribute" (everything is filled in exactly as specified)

Comment: Fixed it now...

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you so much! Exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

The NTLM hash is a MD4 hash of the UTF-16 password. There are many ways to get such an MD4 hash, in addition to the method in the accepted answer :

- Using the Perl `Crypt::SmbHash` module:
  `perl -M'Crypt::SmbHash qw(nthash)' -le 'print nthash(shift)' $Pass`
- Using the Perl Digest::MD4 module (see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/387549/53547))
- Using `openssl`:
  `echo -n "$Pass" | iconv -t utf16le | openssl md4`